# How to stop having to enter password twice to unlock the screen?

Tags: password, authentication, lock-screen, screensaver

Recently when I lock my Ubuntu 14.04 account I have to write my password twice in two different places before getting in. This happened recently. I think I might have installed some stuff that I saw on YouTube and maybe this was one of them. If so, how do I delete stuff that I installed from the terminal?

It must be one of these because those are what I installed from the terminal:

Install pipelight so silverlight works:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install pipelight-multi
```

Enable silverlight plugin:

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

Enable widevine plugin:

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable widevine
```

To get flash woking in chromium (chrome pepperflash):

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

Install restricted extras:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Install unrestricted version of libavcodec for encoding and decoding:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra
```

Comment: "*I have to write my password twice in two different places before getting in.*" Can you describe this in greater detail? It's not clear why you have to enter it twice, or how you're doing so.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following in the terminal:

```
ps aux | grep screensaver
```

Chances are you've got 2 different screensaver daeomns running at the same time. Like gnome-screensaver and mate-screensaver.

For me, because I only use mate, I ended up uninstalling gnome-screensaver.

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall a programm using terminal please use this :

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove packagename
```

Comment: Would that actually fix the problem with unlocking the screen, though?

Comment: isn't his question : how do I delete stuff that I installed from the terminal?  because he thinks his screen is locked doubled because of one of the tools he installed.